# Using carrierwave to upload images as authenticated on cloudinary from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I need to upload images as authenticated on Cloudinary from rails with Carrierwave.

I know how to upload as private with make_private method.

I can upload with the command :

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("Photo No. 11.jpeg", :type => :authenticated)
```

I tried with a custom method 'type' with no effect. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do change type to be `authenticated`, not `authenticate`. It should work.

Make sure that the image parameter should be URL, base64 or local image path.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Of course 'authenticated', i mistype the code above.
The question is, where do i put this in my carrierwave uploader class ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `self.storage_type = :authenticated`.
`make_private` actually does `self.storage_type = :private` internally.

Comment: Yes, this is working perfectly. Same answer than the cloudinary support :)